# C++ Char Initialization Allowed With Multiple Characters

Tags: c++, char

During learning about C++ by reading a book I have seen this (for me) strange line of code.

`char ch('AB'); // Or char ch = 'AB';`

It is strange for me because I don't get that you can assign to a `char` multiple "letters" without getting any exception.

```
cout << "Characters in ch: " << ch << endl; // Output B
```

Why does this work? And how is it working internally? Is it only saving the last character and ignoring the other ones?

Comment: You'll get warned by the compiler. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/26a2279249229f4c

Comment: The exact behavior is implementation defined, according to the specifications. If that same book does not mention to use this with a *specific compiler*, then it's a grave error.

Comment: Btw assigning to many characters which can't be saved as one integer is (at least in visual studio) showing a warning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's called a [**multicharacter literal**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/character_literal) which are completely valid C++:

> Multicharacter literal, e.g. `'AB'`, has type `int` and implementation-defined value.
>
> [...]
>
> Many implementations of multicharacter literals use the values of each char in the literal to initialize successive bytes of the resulting integer, in big-endian order, e.g. the value of `'\1\2\3\4'` is `0x01020304`.

Comment: The notes on that page say "**Many** implementations of multicharacter literal" -  not "all", so it may not be "completely valid".

Comment: Ok, ty thought at first every character is represented by a single byte but I was wrong

Comment: @RadLexus The note you're referring to explains how many implementations implement the behavior. The standard still guarantees that _all_ implementations must implement _some_ behavior, which makes the construct valid C++. Only any specific behavior is not guaranteed regarding the value of the literal.

Comment: The specifications are (possibly deliberately) vague. The construct is valid (it will do *something*) but what happens next is left to implementation. So using OP's example, perhaps `c1 = 'AB'; c2 = 'A';` yields true for `c1 == c2`.

Answer (score 3):

> It is strange for me because I don't get that you can assign to a char multiple "letters" without getting any exception.

You should see it as a type conversion ([demo](http://ideone.com/fpGQwe)):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    {
        int i = 'abcd';
        char c = i; // cast form int to char -> c == 'd'
        cout << c; // prints 'd'
    }

    {
        char c = 'abcd'; // cast form int to char -> c == 'd'
        cout << c; // prints 'd'
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The order in which the characters are stored in int is not specified by standard. However, a well designed compiler will consider endianness when storing a multi-character constant: GCC and VisualC behaves the same way.

Comment: Note that the C++ standard doesn't guarantee that this will print `'d'`. (A specific compiler may guarantee that though.)

Comment: See my edited answer.