# Unreported error VS 2015: Hex char specifier

Tags: c++, char

I wanted this:  `char c = '\x20' ;`
But by mistake I typed this:  `char c = 'x20';`

The VS2015 compiler reported a warning '`converting integer to char`', there was no error, the code ran but the value of c was 48 (decimal). Can anyone explain how the erroneous format conversion works, assuming it is a valid form (I didn't think it was). Or is this maybe an error that VS15 doesn't recognise?

Comment: That's a multi-character literal.

Comment: [What do single quotes do in C++ when used on multiple characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7459939/995714), [C++ Char Initialization Allowed With Multiple Characters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41331212/995714). 48 is 0x30 which is the ASCII code of `'0'` in `'x20'`

Answer (score 1):

`'x20'` is a *multicharacter literal*.  Per [[lex.ccon]/2](http://eel.is/c++draft/lex.ccon#def:literal,multicharacter):

> A character literal that does not begin with `u8`, `u`, `U`, or `L` is
>   an *ordinary character literal*. An ordinary character literal that
>   contains a single *c-char* representable in the execution character
>   set has type `char`, with value equal to the numerical value of the
>   encoding of the *c-char* in the execution character set.
>   **An ordinary character literal that contains more than one *c-char* is a *multicharacter literal*.** A multicharacter literal, or an
>   ordinary character literal containing a single *c-char* not
>   representable in the execution character set, **is
>   conditionally-supported, has type `int`, and has an
>   implementation-defined value.**

Therefore, from a standard perspective, your implementation supports this conditionally-supported construct, and you get an implementation-defined value of type `int` which, when converted to type `char`, results in `char(48)`.

---

Per [Microsoft Visual Studio C++ Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/string-and-character-literals-cpp?view=vs-2019#character-literals):

> #### Microsoft Specific
>
> Multiple characters in the literal fill corresponding bytes as needed
>   from high-order to low-order. To create a `char` value, the compiler
>   takes the low-order byte. To create a `wchar_t` or `char16_t` value,
>   the compiler takes the low-order word. The compiler warns that the
>   result is truncated if any bits are set above the assigned byte or
>   word.
>
> ```
> char c0    = 'abcd';    // C4305, C4309, truncates to 'd'
> wchar_t w0 = 'abcd';    // C4305, C4309, truncates to '\x6364'
> ```

In your case, you use `'x20'`.  The compiler takes the low-order byte — `'0'`, which is `char(48)` under ASCII encoding.